# Selenium tests got slower after update to chrome v96

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After update Google Chrome to v96 selenium tests works slower then expected.

UPD: same problem with v97.

I have simple check (options.headless = True):

```
chrome_args = [
            'window-size=1920,1080',
            'disable-infobars',
            'disable-local-storage',
            'disable-notifications',
            'incognito',
            'no-sandbox',
            'disable-dev-shm-usage',
            'incognito',
            'kiosk'
 ]
```

- Open URL
- Get element by XPATHS
- Save screenshot

Results, in sec. (v95 / v96):

- OPEN URL: 4.816 / 7.864
- OPEN URL: 4.934 / 7.617
- OPEN URL: 4.878 / 7.730
- FIND ELEMENT BY XPATH: 1.794 / 2.921
- FIND ELEMENT BY XPATH: 1.663 / 3.135
- FIND ELEMENT BY XPATH: 1.496 / 2.889
- SAVE SCREENSHOT: 3.886 / 9.070
- SAVE SCREENSHOT: 2.704 / 6.861
- SAVE SCREENSHOT: 3.393 / 8.655

Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: I'm having similar issues. chrome 96 is much more resource intensive, slower on Selenium.

Comment: Confirming too! Headless version for sure. Regular browser seems about the same performance.

Comment: @IkarPohorský do you found solution ? I hope after chrome update it will be fixed but unfortunately after update to v97 it won't fixed

Comment: @VVV Not yet, we froze the selenium nodes on v95 for now :(

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed if using the new headless mode, thank for helping @diemol

```
self.options.add_argument('--headless=new')
```